# How do I use a while loop to continuously open an external python file over and over again

Tags: python-3.x, loops, file, execute

I am attempting to figure out why my code is not working. What I am attempting to do is absolutely stupid but I have tried to do it and failed. I must know why it is not working. I have a python file name hello.py that is as follows:

```
while True:
  print('Hello')
```

I am wanting to create another python file named loop.py that executes hello.py a ton of times in separate instances (in separate windows) in hopes it fills my screen with tons of instances running hello.py. My current code to achieve this is successful in only opening one instance. No more instance pop up after. Just one is ran. Loop.py is as follows:

```
import hello.py
import os

while True:
   os.system('hello.py')
```

Comment: Is there any errors that come with it? Why isn't it working?

Comment: fwiw, you don't need to import `hello.py`

Comment: Your first file is not even valid python.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how exactly the code fails, my two suspicions are:

1. You don’t have execute permissions on `hello.py`
2. Your system/python interpreter expects some other information

Assuming you are using a BSD or GNU/Linux box, my suggestion is to:

1. Add the output/any errors to your question
2. Do a `ls-l` on `hello.py` and ensure you see `”rwx”` for the user permission
3. Add a python shebang ( probably `/usr/bin/python` to `hello.py`
4. Try running `os.system(‘python hello.py’`) to `loop.py`

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what operating system you are using. This answer relates to Linux. I don't use Windows or MacOS, but I assume the solution in their case should be similar.

1) The statement `Print('Hello')` is wrong python syntax. It should be `print('Hello')`

2) Assuming you are in the same directory as hello.py and it contains the code lines in (1) above. Importing it with `import hello.py` will cause the code to run when imported and you will have an infinite loop in your python command window. Fix is to simply run the file with the operating system python using:

```
import os
while True:
    os.system('python3 hello.py')
```